# Multiple snippets in one file sublime text 2

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext, code-snippets

Is it possible to have multiple custom snippets in one file using sublime text 2?
Currently you have to create individual files for each snippet.

Answer (score 11):

You can create a `*.sublime-completions` file. For information on how to do this, see [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html) and [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html).

Comment: Sublime Text 4 now requires the user to press TAB twice with `*.sublime-completions` files. Snippets select the best option on the first TAB keypress.