# Multiple snippets per file in Sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3, code-snippets

Is it possible to define multiple snippets in one single file with Sublime 3?

I have found the [same question from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802912/multiple-snippets-in-one-file-sublime-text-2) but the only answer given at the time referred to two links that are now broken. Probably those two links have been merged into [this one](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html)

But, essentially, I keep wondering if something apparently so simple is now possible.

Comment: I dont think that is possible.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro is correct. A `.sublime-snippet` has one and only one completion in it, but it can span multiple lines if needed. A `.sublime-completions` file can have multiple completions/snippets in it, but due to its JSON formatting, they can only be one-liners.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you, I will try to get it done with completions then...